# Short way to write (\(x, y) -> (f x, g y))

Tags: haskell, tuples

For functions `f :: a → b`, `g :: c → d`, how do I write the lambda

```
\(x, y) → (f x, g y) :: (a, b) → (c, d)
```

more concisely? I tried `(f, g)` but – as was to be expected I guess – without success.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Bifunctor` instance of `(,)` is what you are looking for:

```
instance Bifunctor (,) where
  bimap f g (a, b) = (f a, g b)
```

`bimap` applies two functions to a tuple, one to each element.

```
> import Data.Bifunctor
> bimap (+1) (*5) (1,1)
(2, 5)
```

---

You might be wondering what the difference between `bimap` and `(***)` is.

```
> :t bimap
bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
> :t (***)
(***) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')
```

With `bimap`, you can restrict the type to tuples rather than an arbitrary bifunctor `p`, so that with `p ~ (,)`, the type of `bimap` becomes

```
 (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (a, c) -> (b, d).
```

With `(***)`, you can restrict the type to functions rather than an arbitrary arrow `a`, so that with `a ~ (->)`, the type of `(***)` becomes

```
 (b -> c) -> (b' -> c') -> (b, b') -> (c, c')
```

A close look reveals the two restricted types are equivalent.

Comment: Sadly, that is not exactly the `Bifunctor` instance. It's actually `bimap f g ~(x, y) = (f x, g y)`, which is only "morally correct" and can cause a space leak if you're not careful.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Bifunctor.html#line-78

Comment: Oops, I *thought* I had copied it from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/src/Data-Bifunctor.html), but apparently not. My eye must have glossed over the `~`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `(***)` from `Control.Arrow` i.e.

```
f *** g
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
import Control.Arrow

answer = f *** g $ (a, c)
```

e.g.

```
import Control.Arrow

f :: Int -> Int
f = (+1)

g :: Double -> String
g = show

answer = f *** g $ (10, 3.5)
```